# How do I convert a CoreData date interval to a SQLite date?

Tags: sqlite, date, core-data, timestamp, nsdate

Something went wrong with my app's data! For debugging purposes only, I downloaded the app's container so I could take a look inside it's CoreData `.db` file.

I'm using a SQLite client to query it. I've found that in it, dates (`NSDate`s) are stored as if from the result of `dateToStore.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`, which is the number of seconds since the start of 2001.

SQLite has this nice function which will convert a UNIX timestamp, but those start at the end of 1970:

```
SELECT datetime(ZDATECOLUMN, 'unixepoch') FROM ZTABLENAME
```

So today's date, `2016-05-11`, would have a CoreData timestamp something like `484676143.607`, but a UNIX timestamp like `1462997743.607`. When using the above SQL for my data, today's date would appear as `1985-05-11`. **How do I use SQL to get back these CoreData timestamps as human-readable dates?**

Comment: *"I have an iOS CoreData .db file and I'm using SQLite to query it."* That way lies madness. Why are you doing that?

Comment: @TomHarrington I downloaded it from the device and I'm looking at it to figure out where the data went wrong. Rest assured I'm not having the app query it :P

Comment: You can convert the decimal found in the sqlite to a real date time using http://www.epochconverter.com/coredata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is ancient, but I was trying to do it today. You can use datetime(), you just need to add 978307200 to the coredata timestamp. Coredata timestamps are seconds since 2001-01-01. 978307200 is the difference in seconds between unix epoch and coredata epoch. So, in the form of the original question, you could do this:

```
SELECT datetime(ZDATECOLUMN + 978307200, 'unixepoch') FROM ZTABLENAME
```

Comment: Thanks! 7½ years of experience later, I would have assumed this. I completely forgot about asking this question; thank you for answering it, and welcome to SO!